# Change Image Using IF Statements

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, uiimage

I have setup a fuel bar in my game, but I am trying to use if statements to change the bar image based on how low the fuel percentage is.  For some reason, the image is not changing along with the percentage.  As such, the bar remains full.  What is going on here?

```
fuelRemaining = 100;
    FuelRemaining.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%%", fuelRemaining];
    FuelBar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fuel_bar_100.png"];
    if (fuelRemaining > 90) {
        FuelBar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fuel_bar_100.png"];
    }
    else if (fuelRemaining > 80 && fuelRemaining <= 90) {
        FuelBar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fuel_bar_90.png"];
    }
    else if (fuelRemaining > 70 && fuelRemaining <= 80) {
        FuelBar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fuel_bar_80.png"];
    }
    else if (fuelRemaining > 60 && fuelRemaining <= 70) {
        FuelBar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fuel_bar_70.png"];
    }
    else if (fuelRemaining > 50 && fuelRemaining <= 60) {
        FuelBar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fuel_bar_60.png"];
    }
    else if (fuelRemaining > 40 && fuelRemaining <= 50) {
        FuelBar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fuel_bar_50.png"];
    }
    else if (fuelRemaining > 30 && fuelRemaining <= 40) {
        FuelBar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fuel_bar_40.png"];
    }
    else if (fuelRemaining > 20 && fuelRemaining <= 30) {
        FuelBar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fuel_bar_30.png"];
    }
    else if (fuelRemaining > 10 && fuelRemaining <= 20) {
        FuelBar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fuel_bar_20.png"];
    }
    else if (fuelRemaining > 0 && fuelRemaining <= 10) {
        FuelBar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fuel_bar_10.png"];
    }
    else {
        FuelBar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fuel_bar_0.png"];
    }
```

Comment: You may wish to consider a switch statement instead as an improvement.

Comment: Pro tip: if you give this a little thought you can reduce this huge ugly mess of copy/paste code to just a few lines.

Comment: Incomplete code, but this could help you get started: `FuelBar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"fuel_bar_%lu.png", (unsigned long)fuelRemaining]];` You will need code to round up to the nearest 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, simplify that with some basic math:

```
int fuelRounded = 10.0 * floor((fuelRemaining/10.0)+0.5);
NSString *fuelImageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fuel_bar_%d.png", fuelRounded];
FuelBar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:fuelImageString];
```

(The math may need tweaking depending on your game logic and possible values for `fuelRemaining`.)

Second, it looks like you're setting `fuelRemaining` to `100` at the top of the method. You'll need to set the image again after `fuelRemaining` has changed to something else.

For example:

```
- (void) updateFuelViews {
    FuelRemaining.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%%", fuelRemaining];

    int fuelRounded = 10.0 * floor((fuelRemaining/10.0)+0.5);
    NSString *fuelImageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fuel_bar_%d.png", fuelRounded];
    FuelBar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:fuelImageString];
}
```

Then call `[self updateFuelViews];` every time `fuelRemaining` changes.

You may want to research *Key-Value Observing*, which would let you update the fuel views automatically whenever `fuelRemaining` changes. It's a bit of a headache, but could make it easier to manage if you have lots of stuff changing constantly.